# When %post section runs in an automated Linux installation

Tags: kickstart

I know %post section in kickstart runs after RPM packages are installed in a Red Hat based distribution installation. Question: it runs before or after system is rebooted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the system is rebooted and *after* the packages and bootloader are installed.